# 120v outdoor lighting, dual poser source 150w light

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

So i was trying to think if there was a way to make a 120v  XOR or OR "device" to turn on a lamp. Perhaps with some relays or something to accomplish this general idea.

I want to accomplish this using maximum of 4 wires (not inc. ground). 
and yes i mentioned TTL XOR / TTL OR gate like functionality  but in this case I'm talking 120V AC

[image: want to accomplish this using maximum of 4 wires (not inc. ground)]

see comment #2 for more details...

thoughts anyone?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? Is there any reason a standard 3-way switch won't work? That kind of gives you the same functionality of an XOR in that if either switch is flipped the light will change state. But it's not quite the same since with an XOR, if either switch is turned on, the light will be on but if both are on, then it will not.

Comment: In my case the blue wire is controlled by switch (hot/cold), the second line (red) i plan on hooking to  the "daisy chain" - (ie red output [hot/cold]) wire of a motion sensor...  this way if the switch is "ON' on the blue line the light is "on" ...and it doesn't matter (if the security sensor also turned it "on")... but when blue line is "cold"  the light  is "off", and if in that instance something were to trip the motion sensor the same light would also turn "on" ...even though the switch is "off".  So yeah technically "OR"  logic ok. Note: motion sensor in my case is not near the light.

Comment: Oh. Well that would've really helped.  *tosses out lengthy answer, replaces with another*

Comment: It tends to be best to describe the problem you're attempting to solve, rather than the solution you're trying to create.

Comment: Can you post the model of your motion sensor?

Comment: Ok so im new to this site and dont know why my edits not showing up... guess i should be a bit more careful and not post things at 3am. But as I was saying I understand OR logic would work, was just trying to describe an idea sorry if this ruffled feathers of purists.

Comment: I suppose it could be done with a single DPDT 120v relay but was curious if this was the best way to do this and secondly if anyone had any suggestions for what type of relay would be best for an outdoor light (esp where the bulb could be LED or CFL), and small enough so that could be packed inside a 13-17 cu in. round electrical box. Ill see if i can draw up a better picture rather than using ms-paint for future discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update.  First, you have raw smarts but you are scattered, not able to describe what you want succinctly - and you seem to have no knowledge of code electrical, this stuff can kill you and burn your house down (with the lemons). You need to learn its pecularities (there are many) *before* you attempt to homebrew anything like this.  Like I say, for smart people, knowledge is cheap. Learn more, work less, rather than the other way 'round.

The home automation field is rapidly evolving, and I'd search it to see if someone has already solved your problem.  I bet they have. Then you can install a listed, code legal solution without a lot of work.

If you have to homebrew it, it's straightforward with 2 relays, though, that'll be a lot of wire.  It can be done properly with one relay but you really need to know what you're doing with neutrals and grounds, in the Code paradigm.